# yii2-user. Авторизация в модальном окне

Tags: yii2

Появилась необходимость авторизации пользователя в модальном окне.
Используется https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user

В документации не нашел готового решения.

Есть экшн [логин](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/controllers/SecurityController.php#L145), но он делает редирект.

Библиотека довольно популярная, задача вроде тривиальная, но решения найти не могу.

Есть [issue](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/issues/979), но решения тоже нет.
Подскажите, что делать?

Переопределил метод.

```
if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest || !Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $this->goHome();
    }

    /** @var LoginForm $model */
    $model = \Yii::createObject(LoginForm::className());
    $event = $this->getFormEvent($model);

    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    $this->trigger(self::EVENT_BEFORE_LOGIN, $event);
    if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->getRequest()->post(),'')) {
        if($model->login()){
            $this->trigger(self::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, $event);
            return json_encode(['success'=>1,]);
        }
        else{
            return json_encode(['success'=>0,'error'=>'Неверный логин или пароль']);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Редирект после авторизации нормальная практика, потому что, обычно, надо перерисовать юзербар. Если необходима авторизация с помощью ajax, то следует переопределить соответствующие контроллеры, в экшенах которых отдавать необходимый ответ при успешной авторизации. Этот ответ отлавливать после отправки формы авторизации.

[Как переопределить контроллеры](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/0.9.12/docs/overriding-controllers.md)

Comment: перегрузил метод. Это идеальное решение?

Comment: Сложно сказать насколько оно идеально, но оно точно очень распространенное.